# Reading a serialized dictionary and puring into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

I am trying to get the dictionaries saved in file in a list of dictionaries. My code is the following:
    def load_obj(name):
        with open(name, 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)

```
def read_PEP_Folders(PEPs_read):
    all_dirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(PEPs_read)]
    all_dirs = all_dirs[1:] 
    PEPs_node_list=[]
    folder_name = 0
    count1=0
    count2=0
    for dirs in all_dirs:
        all_files = os.listdir(dirs)
        folder_name += 1
        for file_name in all_files:
            numberName=str(file_name)
            fullFile=dirs +"/"+ numberName
            PEPs_node_list[count1][count2] = load_obj(fullFile)
            count2 +=1
        count1 +=1
    return(PEPs_node_list)
```

I Call the function `read_PEP_Folders(PEPs_read)` and the error is that the following:

```
File "CleanPEPS.py", line 49, in read_PEP_Folders
    PEPs_node_list[count1][count2] = load_obj(fullFile)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You create `PEPs_node_list` as an empty list, and then before appending anything to it, you try to reference an item in it, and then an item within that item. Your first pass through is equivalent to: `PEPs_node_list[0][0]`.

It looks like you may be trying to append the result of `load_obj(fullFile)` to your list, for which you need: `PEPs_node_list.append(load_obj(fullFile))`.

Comment: it is getting just the in the files on the last folder?